# How can I make an unordered list of item transition on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list of image items with a text overlay at the bottom. The text at the bottom are inline elements with different backgrounds and the right block has a p element that displays on hover.

I do not want a bland quick display, I want it to transition in about 0.4s. I seem not to get the targeted style. This is what my code looks like

```
<ul class="slideList">           
  <li data-transition="fade">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469827160215-9d29e96e72f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80"  alt="" width="1920" height="630">

    <div class="service-highlight">
       <a href="services.php" class="services-box"><p>SOME SERVICES:</p></a>
       <div class="services-detail">
          <a href="services.php"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p></a>
         <div class="hide-description">
           <a href="services.php"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li data-transition="fade">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469827160215-9d29e96e72f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80"  alt="" width="1920" height="630">

    <div class="service-highlight">
       <a href="services.php" class="services-box"><p>SOME SERVICES:</p></a>
       <div class="services-detail">
          <a href="services.php"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p></a>
         <div class="hide-description">
           <a href="services.php"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
 <ul>
```

```
.slideList {
  width: 100%;
}
.slideList li {
  position:relative; 
}

.slideList .service-highlight {
  background-color: #0088ff;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  right:0;
}

.slideList .service-highlight p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slideList .service-highlight .services-box{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #003768;
  width: 270px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}

.slideList .service-highlight .services-detail{
  width:calc(100% - 270px);
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.slideList .hide-description {
  display: none;
  font-weight:normal;
}

.slideList .hide-description p {
  font-weight:normal;
  padding-top: 10px 5px 10px;
}
.hide-description {
  display: none;
}

.services-box {
  height: 26px;
  background: #0bf;
}
.service-highlight {
}

.service-highlight:hover .hide-description {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}

.service-highlight:hover .services-box {
  height: 110px;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
      .slideList .service-highlight p {
        display: block;
      }

      .slideList .service-highlight .services-box{
        width: 100%;
      }

      .slideList .service-highlight .services-detail{
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.hide-description {
  opacity: 0;
}
.slideList .hide-description {
  opacity: 0;
  font-weight:normal;
}
.service-highlight:hover .hide-description {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 
    0.01s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This will work for you, transition is applied for thing that are present. Or, for display: none to block transition  will not work. If doesnot work then provide a codepen link. Will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```css
.slideList {
  width: 100%;
}
.slideList li {
  position:relative; 
}

.slideList .service-highlight {
  background-color: #0088ff;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  right:0;
}

.slideList .service-highlight p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slideList .service-highlight .services-box{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #003768;
  width: 270px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}

.slideList .service-highlight .services-detail{
  width:calc(100% - 270px);
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.slideList .hide-description {
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  font-weight:normal;
}

.slideList .hide-description p {
  font-weight:normal;
  padding-top: 10px 5px 10px;
}


.services-box {
  height: 26px;
  background: #0bf;
}
.service-highlight {
}

.service-highlight:hover .hide-description {
      opacity: 1;
      
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}

.service-highlight:hover .services-box {
  height: 110px;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
      .slideList .service-highlight p {
        display: block;
      }

      .slideList .service-highlight .services-box{
        width: 100%;
      }

      .slideList .service-highlight .services-detail{
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
}
```

```html
<ul class="slideList">           
  <li data-transition="fade">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469827160215-9d29e96e72f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80"  alt="" width="1920" height="630">

    <div class="service-highlight">
       <a href="services.php" class="services-box"><p>SOME SERVICES:</p></a>
       <div class="services-detail">
          <a href="services.php"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p></a>
         <div class="hide-description">
           <a href="services.php"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li data-transition="fade">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469827160215-9d29e96e72f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80"  alt="" width="1920" height="630">

    <div class="service-highlight">
       <a href="services.php" class="services-box"><p>SOME SERVICES:</p></a>
       <div class="services-detail">
          <a href="services.php"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p></a>
         <div class="hide-description">
           <a href="services.php"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
 <ul>
```